# is there any way to display database records in one by one textviews i without using listviews

Tags: php, android, mysql, textview

I want to print the specific data returned by sql query to android application..here i want to return two records using limit query. 
This means whenever I put some condition on select query then that type of record will be displayed by textview. 
Can anyone please help me to view the data returned by limit query to one by one textviews without using listviews.

Here is my code

```
MainActivity.java

package com.example.readtoapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getJSON("http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/getdata.php");
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, heroes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}`
```

And below is php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "android";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$heroes = array(); 
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM heroes limit 1;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
while($stmt->fetch()){ 
    $temp = [
        'id'=>$id,
        'name'=>$name
    ]; 
    array_push($heroes, $temp);
}
echo json_encode($heroes);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity_main.xml replace ListView to use TextView and change id to nameTv.

and update this code :

```
TextView nameTv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTv);
    getJSON("http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/getdata.php");
}

private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    String[] heroes = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        heroes[i] = obj.getString("name");
    }
    nameTv.setText(heroes[0]);
}
```